# In WPF, what's the difference between null and Identity for RenderTransform?

Tags: c#, wpf

If I want to clear the RenderTransform on a UIElement, what is the preferred way to do it? Both seem to work:

```
MyGrid.RenderTransform = null;
```

or

```
MyGrid.RenderTransform = Transform.Identity;
```

Does anyone know the difference or if there will be any side effects by setting it to null?

From MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.identity(v=vs.110).aspx

When you apply an identity matrix, it does not change the object. It is like multiplying by 1.

Also, the default value for UIElement.RenderTransform is Transform.Identity.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. In `UIElement.ArrangeCore` source code you can see:

```
protected virtual void ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
{
    this.RenderSize = finalRect.Size;
    Transform transform = this.RenderTransform;
    if (transform == Transform.Identity)
        transform = (Transform) null;
    // the rest ...
}
```

So if `RenderTransform` is identity - it's treated as if it was null.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that it doesn't make much difference if you set the `RenderTransform` property to `null` or `Transform.Identity`, you might probably just want to reset the property to its default value, by

```
MyGrid.ClearValue(UIElement.RenderTransformProperty);
```